# rails How to get image name instead of hash for shrine url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, shrine

Currently when I store any image using shrine uploader then I received url :-

```
/uploads/store/90bcb5a78ed5de16a6c62eea1fb80ed1.png
```

but I want url to be display like:-

```
/uploads/store/original_image_name.png
```

is there any solution

for reference:-

initializer/shrine.rb

```
require "shrine/storage/file_system"
  Shrine.storages = {
    cache: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads/cache"),
    store: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads/store")
  }
```

model/image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < Shrine
  plugin :derivatives
  plugin :url_options, store: { host: "www.cloudfair.com" }
  Attacher.derivatives_processor do |original|
    processor = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(original)
    {
      large:  processor.resize_to_limit!(1280, 800),
      medium: processor.resize_to_limit!(600, 600),
      small:  processor.resize_to_limit!(400, 400),
    }
  end
end
```

to upload image:-

```
photo = Photo.new
photo.image = params[:image_file]
photo.image_derivative!
photo.save()
```

to access image URL:-

```
photo.image(:small).url
```

Comment: Could you include the code you're using to upload the image?

Comment: Sure, I will update it within 5 min

Comment: code updated... please check

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this in your uploader file

```
def filename
  if original_filename
    "#{model.original_filename}.#{file.extension}"
  end
end
```